# Push_back 1D Vector as Row into 2D Vector Array

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax, vector, push-back

I'm trying to define the values of a 'row' or 1D vector and then push_back that row into a 2D vector.  I've tried a couple different things that don't throw errors but also don't seem to work.  Code below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::vector;

#define HEIGHT 5
#define WIDTH 3

// 2D VECTOR ARRAY EXAMPLE

int main() {
vector<vector<double> > array2D;
vector<double> currentRow;

// Set up sizes. (HEIGHT x WIDTH)
// 2D resize
array2D.resize(HEIGHT);
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
{
  array2D[i].resize(WIDTH);
}
// Try putting some values in
array2D[1][2] = 6.0; // this works
array2D[2].push_back(45); // this value doesn't appear in vector output.  Why?

// 1D resize
currentRow.resize(3);

// Insert values into row
currentRow[0] = 1;
currentRow[1] = 12.76;
currentRow[2] = 3;

// Push row into 2D array
array2D.push_back(currentRow); // this row doesn't appear in value output.  Why?

// Output all values
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
{ 
  for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j)
    {  
        std::cout << array2D[i][j] << '\t';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the time you push_back currentRow, array2D already contains HEIGHT rows and after the push_back it will contain HEIGHT+1 rows. You just don't show the last one you added, only the first HEIGHT rows.

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough reputation to upvote you.  But thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`push_back()` appends an item to the end of the vector. If the vector contained `WIDTH` items, it contains `WIDTH+1` items after the `push_back()`.

When you print the contents of the vector, you only print the first `WIDTH` items, even if the vector contains more, so you don't see the additional items.

You can find out how many items are in a vector with the `size()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `resize` when you actually want to use `reserve` method instead. The thing is that resize does change the content of the vector, while reserve just changes the storage capacity. So if you resize a vector to N elements and then push some elements into it, they will be pushed in positions N, N + 1, etc, while if you just reserve size for N elements, they will be pushed in positions 0, 1, etc, which is what you seem to want.